# ¿Cómo puedo limpiar el campo de un Select que usa un chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.multiple').chosen({placeholder_text_multiple: 'Seleccione'});

$(document).on('change','#mes',function(){
  if($(this).val()=="todos"){
  
  }else{      
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control multiple" multiple id="mes">
  <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
  <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
  <option value="junio">Junio</option>
  <option value="julio">Julio</option>
  <option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
  <option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
  <option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
  <option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
  <option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

Tengo un selector que usa la libreria de chosen para poder seleccionar varias opciones, lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione una opcion especifica se limpie el campo y deje el que esta seleccionado por default.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Julian, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. Para que podamos ayudarte has de pulsar en [edit] y explicar con ejemplos la funcionalidad deseada. Tambien, añade el codigo HTML del input y tambien los intentos o investigacion realizada que hiciste para resolverlo porque aqui ayudamos con dudas concretas para ayudarte, no hacemos tareas. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que algo así te puede funcionar. Por defecto está seleccionado la opción "Todos". Si el usuario selecciona la opción "Julio", borra todas las que haya seleccionado antes y deja la que viene por defecto ("Todos").

Para ello comprueba si la opción "julio" está en el array que devuelve `$(this).val()` y si está asigno al `select` el valor "todos" y llamo a `trigger("chosen:updated")` para que actualice el `select` con ese valor por defecto.

```js
$('.multiple').chosen({placeholder_text_multiple: 'Seleccione'});

$(document).on('change','#mes',function(){
  if($.inArray("julio", $(this).val()) > -1){
    $(this).chosen().val('todos').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }else{
  
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control multiple" multiple id="mes">
  <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
  <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
  <option value="junio">Junio</option>
  <option value="julio">Julio</option>
  <option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
  <option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
  <option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
  <option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
  <option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono mucho.

Comment: pero necesito también que si el usuario selecciona otro mes borre la opción de todos y me deje colocar los meses gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto está seleccionado la opción "Todos". Si el usuario selecciona la opción "Todos", borra todas las que haya seleccionado antes y deja la que viene por defecto ("Todos"), pero necesito aparte de eso tambien es que si el usuario selecciona un mes borre la opcion todos o la remplace con el mes que el usuario elija.

```js
$('.multiple').chosen({placeholder_text_multiple: 'Seleccione'});

$(document).on('change','#mes',function(){
  if($.inArray("todos", $(this).val()) > -1){
    $(this).chosen().val('todos').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }else{
  
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control multiple" multiple id="mes">
  <option value="todos" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="enero">Enero</option>
  <option value="febrero">Febrero</option>
  <option value="marzo">Marzo</option>
  <option value="abril">Abril</option>
  <option value="mayo">Mayo</option>
  <option value="junio">Junio</option>
  <option value="julio">Julio</option>
  <option value="agosto">Agosto</option>
  <option value="septiembre">Septiembre</option>
  <option value="octubre">Octubre</option>
  <option value="noviembre">Noviembre</option>
  <option value="diciembre">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```